# I'm trying to create a button below a listView and all of that within a modalBottomSheet, but I'm failing at that

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is the code I have so far, the error is when I try to put it inside a column, but without the column, right in the listView.separeted does not allow me to add a button.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return BottomSheet(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
          onClosing: () {},
          builder: (context) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.separated(
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    const Divider(),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                        10, 10, 10, MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                    itemCount: _playersList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      _controlers.add(TextEditingController());
                      return TextField(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: _playersList[index].name,
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                        controller: _controlers[index],
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      );
                    }),
                RaisedButton(onPressed: null, child: Icon(Icons.save))
              ],
            );
          });
    });
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Set *shrinkWrap* as true in ListView.separated .

Comment: I'm a beginner in flutter, I didn't know it was so easy. Thank you so much!!